# Excel New Column Distinct Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

| STUDENT | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | cat, dog |  |  |  |  |  |
| B |  |  | cat |  |  | dog |  |
| C |  |  | fox, fox |  |  |  |  |
| D | fox, fox |  |  | fox |  |  | dog |

This is my data and for each STUDENT (A, B, C, D) I wish to create in the new column WANT
the sequence of ALL entries, so end up with this:

| STUDENT | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | WANT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | cat, dog |  |  |  |  |  | cat, dog |
| B |  |  | cat |  |  | dog |  | cat; dog |
| C |  |  | fox, fox |  |  |  |  | fox, fox |
| D | fox, fox |  |  | fox |  | dog |  | fox, fox; fox; dog |

I tried `J2`: `=UNIQUE(B2:H2)` with no successes

Comment: Did you consider using `TEXTJOIN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comment section of the question:

```
=BYROW(B2:H5, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN("; ",,x)))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

**Note**: Remember, if the resulting string exceeds `32767` characters (cell limit), `TEXTJOIN` returns the `#VALUE!` error.